# How to post multiple string values in httpclient post

Tags: c#

How do I post multiple string values in an `HttpClient` post?

Below is the code to build the parameters,

```
string s1 = "hi";
string s2 = "hello";    

"&param1="+s1+"&param2="+s2
```

My Web Api method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage SaveItem(string param1,string param2)
{
    // what to write here???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating your values, you could use the [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method to build your querystring :

```
var querystring = String.Format("&param1={0}&param2={1}",s1,s2);
```

Or in newer version of C#, you can use the [String Interpolation operator `$`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) to do the same thing :

```
var querystring = $"&param1={s1}&param2={s2}";
```

**Consider Encoding Your QueryString**

As [Slaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) mentioned, it's generally a good idea to encode these parameters, especially if you are going to be accepting non-alphanumeric input or input that could interfere with your expected behaviors (e.g. '#', '&', etc.). You can do this in several ways such as the [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) method or if you are working outside of a Web application, [`WebUtility.UrlEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
// Use HttpUtility for Web Applications and WebUtility for non-web ones
var querystring = $"&param1={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s1)}&param2={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s2)}");
```

The [`Server.URLEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx) method is another popular option as well, which essentially accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: You need to escape the values.

Comment: That's a good point Slaks. I've added a section that covers this as well.

Comment: Hey, I have POST method in Web API. So how to call this method from client using HTTPclient. Can I call like this client.PostAsync("http://localhost/OPUS/Customer/GetCustomer?CutomerId=34&DeptId=12")

Comment: Yes, that should work. The `PostAsync()` method will as expected perform an HTTP `POST` as opposed to a `GET`, which should hit the corresponding action within your API.